# Add column to matrix in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am working with Power BI Desktop and I need to add a column to a matrix in order to calculate totals without adding to each column.

This is my original table:

[image: Original table]

I have two calculated measures: `[Overdue Balance]` and `[Expiring Balance]` that together results in the measure `[Accounting Balance]` (in the previous image is **Total**).

I'd like to add both calcuated measures as totals in the previous table (only as totals, not as column values).

[image: Desired table]

Any ideas to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in your current layout. What you can do instead: create separate measures for each age bucket and for the totals, and put them into the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of web digging we achieved this by doing the following:

1. I created two tables with one bucket each other like: [Created Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDT3d.png)
2. I added two conditional columns with each bucket to the accounting balance table according to the calculated measure `[Expiration days]`:

**Expiring bucket**:

- If `[Expiration days]` is greater or equal to 0 then value is 1.
- If `[Expiration days]` is greater than 30 then value is 2.
- ...
- If `[Expiration days]` is greater than 180 then value is 7.
- Otherwise is 8.

Then I did the same for the **Overdue bucket** column:

- If `[Expiration days]` is less to 0 then value is 1.
- If `[Expiration days]` is less than -30 then value is 2.
- ...
- If `[Expiration days]` is less than -180 then value is 7.
- Otherwise is 8.

Therefore a record would have both columns like:

> - **ID:** whatever
> - **Expiration days:** 24
> - **Expiring bucket:** 1
> - **Overdue bucket:** 8

3. I made the relation from the accounting balance table to both created tables
4. Then I made the tables and they were sorted like this: [Resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm8Pg.png)